# How can we simulate starvation in executor framework?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I want to simulate a hung thread which we faced in production environment. The application is a web service and different threads are created for new requests. The bug was that all threads were dependent on a synchronized method and that dependency has been removed in patch..
Any pointers how can we simulate the hung threads of executor framework in dev environment?

In Dev, everything is fine, how can I ensure some thread hung for that sync method just like production?

```
 package com.priority;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class StackOverFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            executorService.submit(new Task());
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

}

class Task implements Runnable {
    synchronized void syncMethod() {
        System.out.println("This is the sync method causing issues");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        syncMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not nearly enough information to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the synchronized resource (synchronized void syncMethod()) is in some other class so that it is accessible to threads outside of the executorservice. This refactoring is is needed to re-create the starvation scenario.

Create few greedy threads who would hold on to the synchronized resource for random periods (more than normal threads). The number of such threads could be dependent on your test scenario.

Trigger greedy threads before your executor service so that they acquire the resource .

Now you could test how your real threads responds in case of resource scarcity and also define a strategy to manage resource in case of uneven usage.

Answer (score 0):

Without explicit object, `synchronized` will be performed on `this`, so the code you posted does not synchronize.

You should give these tasks the same monitor lock:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class StackOverFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object monitor = new Object();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            executorService.submit(new Task(monitor));
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

}

class Task implements Runnable {
    Object monitor;

    public Task(Object monitor) {
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    void syncMethod() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            System.out.println("This is the sync method causing issues");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        syncMethod();
    }
}
```